# При попытке создать инстанс Firefox в Selenium выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, firefox, тестирование, selenium-webdriver, автоматизация

SeleniumWD 3.0.2, Firefox 51.0.1, Python 3.5.2
При банальной попытке использовать Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Получаю такую картину:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected
browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default
location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no
binary flag set on the command line
```

то есть не находит бинарников. Есть возможность прописать путь к binary, но хотелось бы без этих танцев с бубном.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно указать путь к драйверу.
Пример для хрома:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/user/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
```

Драйвер можно [скачать](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).